# No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, pyinstaller, exe

I've created a Python script to store data in MySQL. It works properly in PyCharm. When converted to an `exe` file it does not work.

This is traceback from the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
[8428] Failed to execute script 'myscript' due to unhandled exception!
```

The command to create the `exe`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --console CoinVolumes.py
```

I also tried `auto-py-to-exe` but got the same error. Mysql is installed.

Comment: I've had to add modules through `--hidden-import` with pyinstaller before, but that's always been because I was using things that weren't directly imported in code.  I'd bet that the problem is related to the pyinstaller search path.  It's just not seeing mysql even though it's there.

Answer (score 5):

use this command:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

after that verify:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Apr 26 2016, 13:18:56)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

Comment: Its installed:
```
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.```

Comment: the import? @ArūnasVyšniauskas

Comment: Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>

Comment: so it suppose to work @ArūnasVyšniauskas

Comment: C:\Users\david>python
Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6.9 I can use Pip 3 and do following:

```
pip3 install mysql
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: Hey, No, I am using Python 3.10.0

Comment: Sorry, I read the comment from the other person which says 2.7.11. I use Python 3.6.9 and have just tried: pip3 install mysql. I also see pip3 install mysql-connector-python

Comment: Yeah, I have both of them installed, but still same thing.

Comment: So they are installed, but Python cannot find the files. In that case, calculate an absolute path to the files and do first:  import sys, sys.path.append('/path/to/the/mysql-library'), import mysql... or maybe 1 directory higher.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run the mysql server yourself. Pyinstaller is working properly, the problem here is that mysql server is not part of python, therefore you need to start the server mannualy. An alternative is to use sqlite, which does not require a server. It is built into standard python, no need for installing anything.

Comment: Server is opened on my computer, but I still get same error.

Comment: Then the problem is in the installed packages of your enviroment as mentioned in other answers. Maibe reinstall mysql and mysql-connector-python, and try again. Also make shure you are inside the correct enviroment before executting pyinstaller

Comment: It is working with PyCharm, so I guess the Mysql Database is installed from https://dev.mysql.com/ (or MariaDB). SqLite is ok for a small database only, or use in RAM before you save this. It becomes very slow, since every change needs to re-write the entire database to disk.